# C# Execution Performance

Tags: c#, performance

I am trying to figure out which of these codes would execute more efficiently. I wanting empirical answers only as I don't fully understand how to test this. If there is a good way to test, I would appreciate these suggestions as well. If this post should not be here, I'm happy to remove it, I just really want to know.

Thanks!

Global Variable :

```
const string FILTER_PLACE_HOLDER = ">-- All Locations --<";
```

Method 1 (What I'm currently using) :

```
ddnZipCode.Text = FILTER_PLACE_HOLDER;
Boolean EnableZipSelection = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() == FILTER_PLACE_HOLDER;
ddnZipCode.Enabled = EnableZipSelection;
```

Method 2 :

```
if (((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() == FILTER_PLACE_HOLDER)
{
   ddnZipCode.Enabled = true;
}
   else
{
   ddnZipCode.Enabled = false;
}
```

Method 3 :

```
ddnZipCode.Enabled = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() == FILTER_PLACE_HOLDER ? true : false;
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a performance issue?

Comment: They will all perform identically.  You should always use the most readable option, which is the first one.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the compiler didn't see those as pretty much exactly the same thing. I'd agree with Brian though that there probably is no performance issue here.

Comment: How could you possibly think that adding extra boolean comparisons will make it run faster, given that your first code is strictly less work?

Comment: Seems like http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the place

Comment: The HTTP turnaround will take at least 4-5 milliseconds. The changes you are proposing will impact for at most 10-20 cycles on the server, which are less than 1 microsecond (a thousands of a millisecond) so why bother at all?

Comment: nano optimisation, maximum effort minimum:w return

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Amen!

Comment: Here's some recommended reading material: http://scientopia.org/blogs/goodmath/2011/05/03/the-perils-of-premature-optimization/

Answer (score 0):

You can test the performance of all methods like this:
remember that if times remain the same, increase the value of the "max" variable  to realize a considerable time difference.

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

int i = 0;
int max = 10000000;

watch.Start();
while (i < max)
{
 //call the method to test
 i++;
}
watch.Stop();

MessageBox.Show("Elapsed time of the Test 1 : " + watch.Elapsed.ToString();
```

Comment: You should throw away the first 100-1000 runs because they will be impacted by memory allocation and not be representative for the actual performance.

Comment: This will measure the time needed to JIT the method under test as well, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know the namespace, Stopwatch is System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch